# What does method renaming works in python class?

Tags: python

So i have been seeing this kind of code and wondering what does it mean in python ?

```py
1   class Client:
2       def __init__(self, adapter=None):
3           self.adapter = adapter
4           self.base_url = '/mock/'
5   
6       def __test__(self):
7           print('enter')
8           return self
9       
10      def __exit__(self, type, exec, tb):
11          print('exit')
12      
13      __enter__ = __test__
14      
15      
16  with Client() as c:
17      print('hi')
```

```py
import utils
class A():
    def a(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        pass

    __repr__ = __str__
    __eq__ = utils.test
```

```py
class A():
    def __str__(self):
        return 'hi'

A.__doc__ = """The docstring"""
```

I understand that the `__enter__` method of the class is mapped to `__test__` method. I want to understand in depth.

What other possibilities are there in python ? I am looking for some examples.

Thanks to the awesome community.

Answer (score 1):

> What other possibilities are there in python ?

In python, class body is simply an executable block of code. When the interpreter sees a class definition, it creates a new scope/namespace, executes the class body in that namespace, and then converts the namespace it creates into the class attributes. You can put pretty much any python code in the block, for examples:

1. an if statement to conditionally define certain methods or attributes based on runtime conditions:

   ```
   class Foo:
       if debug:
           def blah(self):
               ...
   ```
2. a for loop to generate large swaths of methods:

   ```
   class Foo(object):
       for i in open("file.txt"):
           locals()["do_" + str(i)] = decorator(methods[name], name)
   ```
3. assertions to crash the program if certain conditions aren't met:

   ```
   class Foo(object):
       foo = calculate_blah()
       assert os.name == "posix" or "buzz" in foo, "foo must contain buzz in non-POSIX systems"
   ```

or pretty much anything else.

Comment: so it is executed once?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how does `__str__ = __repr__` maps `__str__` func to a `__repr__` method of a class ?

Comment: `__str__ = __repr__` is simply a variable assignment, in python functions are objects just like everything else, the namespace now contains essentially `{"__str__": <function>, "__repr__": <function>}`, which when turned into class simply becomes what you expect. Functions in a class attribute is converted to a bound method through the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Ryan.